Fetching multiple values from an array of objects and passing it as a payload to the next request in JMeter
I have 2 APIs in my script, the response of the first API looks like below:
    "result": [
        {
            "identifier": "test_content_123456789",
            "downloadUrl": "test",
            "description": "desc",
        },
        {
            "identifier": "test_content_6501234",
            "downloadUrl": "test",
            "description": "desc",
        }
    ],
    "key2": [],
    "key3": 1,
    "key4": [
        "status",
        "type",
        "search"
    ],
    
}

From the above response, I need to fetch all the values of the key "identifier" and pass it as a payload to the next request like below:
{"content_id":["test_content_123456789","test_content_6501234"],"source_fields":["test","content_id"],"user_id":["123456"]}
Is it possible using any postprocessors in JMeter?


Add JSR223 PostProcessor as the child of the request which returns the above JSON

Put the following code into "Script" area:
def payload = [:]

payload.put('content_id', new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).result.identifier.collect())
payload.put('source_fields', ['test', 'content_id'])
payload.put('user_id', ['123456'])

vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())


Refer generated value as ${payload} where required


More information:

Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON
The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter

